# Is it possible to freeze and dump state of program?

Tags: c++, linux, serialization

Consider such situation:
There is simple program:

```
int main()

{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i == 50){
            // ... dump state of program somewhere
        }
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to "save" a state of program maybe by storing this state to a file on disk? For example, after some weeks I want to load this state from file and it will continue to work from last stop place (it will print `50 51 ...`).

Comment: The simplest way would be is to rewrite your program, such that it will receive a specific signal, and save it's own state somewhere. And then will check the state on the subsequent runs.

Comment: What do you want to "continue" doing? What do you mean by freeze? What does your program do?

Comment: The technique you need is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: There will be one answer if the event that "freezes" the program is known internally - even at compile time - and another answer if there is an as yet unknown moment when the program will be "frozen".

Comment: You could generate a crash dump, but that's compiler specific and may not contain the entire program state, particularly if it's a release build.

Comment: What is the concrete use case? What kind of application are you coding? Please **edit your question** to improve it and give a lot more context & motivation.

Comment: Programs are never that simple, and the evil is in the details. It is sad that you do not motivate your question and tell a lot more about your application.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called [**application checkpointing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing). Read also the [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating), [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) (& [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)), [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (because copying GC use algorithms very close to those needed for checkpointing), [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), [process migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_migration) wikipages because they are all relevant.

Of course, in limited cases, you could dump a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) and restart it (as suggested by most other answers). But that might not work:

- if your (checkpointed) process has network connections to other servers (e.g. is using [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to access remote web pages or contents).
- if your process has started other processes and is communicating thru pipes or fifos with them
- if your process depends upon external services, such as a database server.
- if your process has a [Graphical User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) (it is communicating with an X11 or Wayland server).
- if you want to restart your process a few weeks later, and you have slightly improved and recompiled its code (even in some places unrelated to the computation), or perhaps just upgraded external libraries, the C++ compiler, or changed compilation (e.g. optimization) flags.
- for multi-threaded applications, you'll have a lot of additional problems (e.g. how to restart them from a checkpointed state, etc...)

In **some cases**, you might **use some checkpointing library** for that. Look into [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/)

In other cases, it is **above the state of the art and is still an active research topic**. You could work about ten years on it and get a PhD.

In practice, checkpointing is so important that you should *think about it before starting to code your first C++ line*. It has a profound impact on the design of your software architecture.

In some cases it would even worth spending a few weeks to develop specialized C++ code generators (to generate the code for persistence & checkpointing).

In some domains, particularily HPC & many scientific computations on [supercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer), checkpointing is essential; for example simulating the collision of two galaxies may requires months of computation on a very costly supercomputer (which might be rebooted before the end of such a huge simulation), and then of course you need to think about checkpointing before writing the first line of code. It could actually be simple (in principle) if the code is very iterative in nature, because you "just" need to save the data computed inside some high-level loop. In practice, it is complex and the evil is in the details.

Some language implementations have limited support for checkpointing. For example (in Common Lisp) [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) offers its [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image) primitive. GNU emacs has [unexec](http://emacshorrors.com/posts/unexecute.html) (but look also [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/673724/), because it could become obsolete).

Application persistence and data is a very important subject. In many cases, the data is more worthwhile than the application itself (then, you should be interested in databases, from [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) to [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) & [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/)).

PS. It is quite unfortunate that your question does not give a lot more context & motivation. Are you sure that it is not an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff you normally need to do manually. With your example:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream input("program_status.txt");
    int start = 0;
    if (input.good())
        input >> start; // TODO Validate!!!

    for (int i = start; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << i << " ";
        if (i == 50){
            ofstream output("program_status.txt");
            // continue next time
            output << (i+1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux core definitely can do that, as program state can be stored in swap area if necessary and then restored back. Only question is if such functionality is provided by API. As match as I know it is not available and I seriously doubt it will be ever. This task is too complex to implement - you need to store all open files, sockets, IPC resources etc. And it is not clear what to do when you try to restore state, but file, which was opened by your program is missing. With TCP sockets it is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

The technique I show you will only work with simple program.
As Slava talked about, all devices and resources previously opened won't be reachable. It will only work with simple program, without no file or socket opened.

1) verify with ulimit -a the ability to create core file. If value if the core size is 0, no core will be created, so increase the value to the size enough to contain your program. You can set with ulimit -c

2) start your simple program, and get the PID of it.

3) send kill -SIGABRT , your program will be stopped and a core dump file will be created with PID as suffix.

The core dump file is your stopped running program. To restart it, use gdb

1) gdb myprogram core.PID

You will see some thing like:

"Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted."

2) start you program with gdb command run.

Last point, if you want generate again a new stopped point with gdb, you can send SIGABRT again to your program, but you will need to generate manually the core file, that is not automatically generated when your program is running with gdb .

The gdb command to generate the core file is : generate-core-file